# (Django) Why my login only work for db table:auth_user can't work another table:myapp_user?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Sorry bad English!

I have a login function in my project like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib import auth
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render 

def log_in(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = auth.authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/index')
    context = {
    'form': form,
    }   
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

This function can work for any accounts that save in database table:auth_user,but can't work for my define class User:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
     BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser  )

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        username = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=20,default="")
        email = models.EmailField()
        date_of_birth = models.DateField()
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        objects = AccountManager()
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'username' #類似主鍵的功用
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','username'] #必填
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
    
        def is_staff(self):
            return self.is_admin
    
        def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
            return self.is_admin
            
        def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
            return self.is_admin
```

If I use register page to create a new account data,it will save in table:function_user("function" is my app name),and if my login table:auth_user accounts it will jump to /index,this right,but when I login new register account,it not do anything , I really sure the username and password is already created in table:function_user.

register(it seems to work properly, the data will save in function_user):

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/index')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

Database
[image]

I want my newly created User account (i.e. function_user) to be able to login in addition to the auth_user.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add custom user model in settings.py file

add following line in settings.py

replace users with your app name in which your custom User model is present

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
After adding it, I can login User now!
An additional question, what should I do if I want the login can work auth_user too?
That is to say, can be used simultaneously two or more tables.

Comment: if you got your answer, tick the answer as correct and upvote :)

Comment: No problem,
but sorry I m new,what should I do??
,If is "This answer is useful" 
That say "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."
My account reputation seems to be insufficient